# How to fix "sqlite3. Operational Error: Incomplete Input"

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

This is my code:

```
#Query the database.
delete = delete_box.get()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE oid = " + delete)

records = c.fetchall()
```

And it always shows me this:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE oid = " + delete)
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

Why is that?. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: have you tried printing out the string `("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE oid = " + delete` to see if it's what you think it is, and to validate that it's valid sql?

Comment: Obviously `delete` is empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to learn how to bind variables in python. From [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-placeholders-to-bind-values-in-sql-queries)

> SQL operations usually need to use values from Python variables. However, beware of using Python’s string operations to assemble queries, as they are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

You can use either style described here:

> An SQL statement may use one of two kinds of placeholders: question marks (qmark style) or named placeholders (named style). For the qmark style, parameters must be a sequence whose length must match the number of placeholders, or a ProgrammingError is raised. For the named style, parameters should be an instance of a dict (or a subclass), which must contain keys for all named parameters; any extra items are ignored.

See [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-placeholders-to-bind-values-in-sql-queries) for examples.